Mullvad vpn loses vpn access randomly
I am using mullvad vpn, and I am connected - see status:
jpc@home:~/mullvad-vpn$ mullvad status -v
Connected to se-got-wg-005 (185.209.199.2:7457/UDP) in Gothenburg, Sweden
Tunnel type: WireGuard
Quantum resistant tunnel: no
Tunnel interface: wg-mullvad

When I exclude a process from mullvad, it works perfectly fine:
jpc@home:~/mullvad-vpn$ mullvad-exclude ping google.com
PING google.com(ord38s31-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:81a::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ord38s31-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:81a::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=21.2 ms
64 bytes from ord38s31-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:81a::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=16.6 ms
64 bytes from ord38s31-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:81a::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=16.0 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 16.028/17.940/21.237/2.340 ms

However running the same command through mullvad fails:
jpc@home:~/mullvad-vpn$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

This recently started happening even though I've been using mullvad successfully for months.
I was able to "fix" the DNS issue by temporarily updating /etc/resolv.conf to use nameserver 8.8.8.8. However this is not ideally, and just led to another problem:
jpc@home:~/mullvad-vpn$ sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
jpc@home:~/mullvad-vpn$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
jpc@home:~/mullvad-vpn$ ping google.com
PING google.com(arn09s20-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400f:80d::200e)) 56 data bytes
From 2601:401:100:e1a:e80e:4746:2e04:8900 (2601:401:100:e1a:e80e:4746:2e04:8900) icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Port unreachable
From 2601:401:100:e1a:e80e:4746:2e04:8900 (2601:401:100:e1a:e80e:4746:2e04:8900) icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Port unreachable
From 2601:401:100:e1a:e80e:4746:2e04:8900 (2601:401:100:e1a:e80e:4746:2e04:8900) icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Port unreachable
From 2601:401:100:e1a:e80e:4746:2e04:8900 (2601:401:100:e1a:e80e:4746:2e04:8900) icmp_seq=4 Destination unreachable: Port unreachable
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3004ms


Anyone have ideas what's going on? This just started happening in the last couple of days

Edit - more information here (size is too large to add to the body of this): https://paste.jpc.io/snippet/2d8fdc8a-2075-461b-bc97-4755f4f0674e

Maybe it's because Mullvad implements some kind of "kill switch", while the physical link still have a link DNS server set in resolved, resulting in DNS requests "leaked but not leaked" from time to time. Add the untampered /etc/resolv.conf and output of resolvectl after the VPN connection is brought up, preferably with the output of iptables-save and nft list ruleset. (Personally I clear the link DNS server of the physical link temporarily with resolvectl when I connect to my personal wg server, and revert the setting when I disconnect. (wg-quick allows up/down actions).

Thanks for looking into this, I've added the output of all those things to this paste (the output is too large to include in my post): https://paste.jpc.io/snippet/2d8fdc8a-2075-461b-bc97-4755f4f0674e

Well, first of all, I'd suggest that you delete the current /etc/resolv.conf (which is a symlink) and recreate one that links to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf (or /usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf, if that doesn't exist). Then preferably just reboot and check cat /etc/resolv.conf and resolvectl again, before and after bring up the mullvad respectively (and create a paste again with the four outputs). Btw, does your physical link have IPv6 connectivity? And does the Mullvad tunnel offers IPv6 connectivity?

If you can't afford to reboot, bring down the mullvad first, and bring down whatever network manager you use (e.g. systemd-networkd), maybe also flush the IP addresses on the physical link, then change the /etc/resolv.conf symlink, then restart systemd-resolved and the network manager, then perform the checks / dumping I mentioned above (with bringing up mullvad again in between).
